# What does でござんしょうな mean in 馬車はいつ出るのでござんしょうな

Tags: grammar, politeness, dialects, particle-な

> 馬車はいつ出るのでござんしょうな

Does this sentence mean "When will the horse cart come out?"

But what does でござんしょうな mean here? Should this be broken down into three parts as で + ござんしょう + な?

I know ございます means have. But ござんしょう becomes let's have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ござんしょう is ございましょう said with an accent. でございましょう is a politer version of でしょう. な is a sentence-end particle (the same な as in ～かな).

> 馬車はいつ出るのでござんしょうな。
>   ≒ 馬車はいつ出るのでございましょうな。
>   ≒ 馬車はいつ出るのでしょうな。

In accented speech, ございます can change to ござんす, ございやす, ごぜえやす, etc.